# How to enable google authentication in pyramid framework?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, pyramid, google-api-python-client

Created client id and secret id using this link https://console.cloud.google.com/

How to proceed the next step to communicate google-oauth in pyramid framework?

Comment: After reading [Pyramid's documentation on security](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/security.html), what have your tried?

Comment: I did some coding back in a day here https://github.com/websauna/websauna/blob/master/websauna/system/user/googleoauth.py